# Message=SelectedDate value is not valid

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I might be tired but why it this throwing an exception:

```
 this.SomeDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Same happens with:

```
 this.SomeDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

The error message is:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=SelectedDate value is not valid.
Parameter name: d
  Source=PresentationFramework
  ParamName=d
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Controls.Calendar.OnSelectedDateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
       at System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker.CoerceSelectedDate(DependencyObject d, Object value)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProcessCoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EntryIndex& entryIndex, Int32& targetIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& oldEntry, Object& oldValue, Object baseValue, Object controlValue, CoerceValueCallback coerceValueCallback, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, Boolean skipBaseValueChecks)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       ....
```

Comment: are you sure about date-time format ? I mean if **your** `DateTime.Now` corresponds to that one assigned to the control ?

Comment: You lead me to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12115476/20654

Answer (score 6):

That exception is thrown if the date you're setting is present in [`BlackoutDates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.blackoutdates.aspx).

The `AddDaysInPast` method should be equivalent to:

```
Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)));
```

so unless the current time changes between the call to `AddDaysInPast` and the `SelectedDate` assignment you should not be having the problem you described.

In debug get the complete ranges present in `BlackoutDates` and update your question with that information, you can use something like:

```
string ranges = string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    DatePicker.BlackoutDates.Select(r => string.Concat(r.Start, "|", r.End)));
```

Comment: I do :-o I added DatePicker.BlackoutDates.AddDaysInPast ( or something similar )  Followup question is, how do I reset the date?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the date?"

Comment: I'm using this window with an option "Inmediate"  or "Picka a date"... if the user picks a date.. well I take that date. If the user choose "Inmediate" I should reset that date to "today"

Comment: You're using DataBinding?...does your DataContext have a DateTime property you can bind the DatePicker's SelectedDate to? (e.g. <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=MyDateProperty}"/>

Comment: @OscarRyz how were you setting the blackout dates in XAML? I'm curious if there's an issue with the AddDaysInPast. I'd keep two properties on my ViewModel (i.e. DataContext) "Yesterday" and "SelectedDate". BlackoutDates in XAML are set FromDate="1/1/0001" to ToDate="Yesterday". Any time the user clicks "Immediate", set SelectedDate = DateTime.Today. Haven't tested it but I'd think that's work.

Answer (score 2):

If `DateTime.Now` is outside of the range defined by DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd OR included in `BlackoutDates`then the exception is thrown.

Comment: At least in .NET 4.0 setting `SelectedDate` automatically adjusts `DisplayDateStart` or `DisplayDateEnd` if needed so in that case no exception is thrown.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo, even if you explicitly set them?

Comment: Yep, I confirmed with a small sample and `DisplayStartDate` was adjusted to the day I set because it was older than the previous explicit start date.

Comment: MSFT should update the MSDN page for SelectedDate then. It lead me to believe otherwise.

Comment: Indeed, I just provided feedback alerting to that problem, lets hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Look:

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException:** The specified date is not in the range defined by DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd, or the specified date is in the BlackoutDates collection.

Font: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate.aspx

Look Exceptions!

You need of date and time or date only?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // only date
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"); // date and hour
```

Comment: I need to set the DatePicker date to today for a given use case ( the user selects something like a button/label : "Today"  and the control should be marked with today's date

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you João Angelo, Ryan answers and Ascension answers I could get the desired result:

```
if ( IsInmediate ) 
{
     SomeDatePicker.BlackoutDate.Clear();
     SomeDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
     SomeDatePicker.BlackoutDate.AddDatesInPast();
}
```